# How to fix (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) when adding action with jquery scripts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress theme from scratch, but when adding

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
```

to have my js script alert pop up on the page I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', 1, true); '
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

for that line

```
function include_jquery() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery3.3.1.min.js, '', 1, true);
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');
```

I expected the code to bring up my alert from my js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  alert('test');
})
```

Comment: You have a missing `'` after the jquery.min.js string. I'd strongly suggest using a IDE with syntax highlighting as it makes typos like this almost impossible to miss.

Comment: yup, use an IDE or just setup your text editor with a linter plugin, it'll help you to prevent a typo

Comment: thanks, will do guess I'm tired I found other 3 basic mistakes, might as well be a blind man trying to code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo. Change

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery3.3.1.min.js, '', 1, true);
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery3.3.1.min.js', '', 1, true);
```

Comment: omg embarrassing sorry I've been coding for 7-8 hours and started this about 2 hours ago, but wanted to finish it before sleeping, thank you

Comment: I know the feeling. Just remember, parse errors are always your fault ;-)

Comment: that I didn't know, thank you very much